# Macro wont delete all blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

This is a longish query because I include failed code.

The Problem: When I have finished importing a text file to excel, my worksheet contains a number of 'blank' cells. I've used the following code successfully before elsewhere but it it not working for me on this occasion.

```
Range("b1:AZ60").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
```

I've searched the web and found a number of proposed solutions (below). I've tried running each of the 4 snipets of code below before my code above to clear the contents of supposedly blank cells but nothing has worked so far.

Number 1---------------------------------------------------------

```
 Set rng = Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange)

For Each C In rng
   If Trim(C) = "" Then
   C.ClearContents
   End If
Next C
```

I've replaced the trim above with c.value but nothing

```
If C.Value <> "" Then
```

Number 2--------------------------------------------------

```
For Each aCell In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Not aCell.Value Like "*[! ]*" Then aCell.ClearContents
Next
```

Number 3-------------------------------------------------

```
For Each C In rng
   If IsEmpty(C) Then
   C.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
   Else
   ActiveCell.Select
   End If
Next C
```

Number 4--------------------------------------

Finally I found this clean function, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

```
Set rng = Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange)

For Each C In rng
    If Not IsError(C) Then
        C.Value = MEGACLEAN(C)
    End If
Next C
              '
              '
              '
End Sub
-----------------------------------------
Function MEGACLEAN(varVal As Variant)
Dim NewVal As Variant
If IsMissing(varVal) Then Exit Function
NewVal = Trim(varVal) 'remove spaces
NewVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(NewVal) 'remove most unwanted characters
NewVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(NewVal, Chr(127), "") 'remove   
ASCII#127
NewVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(NewVal, Chr(160), "") 'remove  
ASCII#160
MEGACLEAN = NewVal
End Function
```

Perhaps it is something to do with the text file I imported from but none of these have worked satisfactorily as I still have a few blank cells. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: can you post a sample of your text file?

Comment: or a sample of the excel file including the "blank" cells

Comment: or have you tried going into whatever blank cells are left to see what character is in there that is causing them to appear blank but not be?

Comment: I bet there is a carriage return that is messing things up. Try a replace on the blank cells removing carraige returns

Comment: check the cells to see if they are really plank with `?len(range("A1"))` in the immediate window. A result other than zero means the cells are not really blank. If you want to check the actual text, this code `for i=1 to len(range("A1")):?asc(mid(range("A1"),i,1));";";:next` will show you the ascii values of the characters

Comment: @ Sorceri, thanks but I'm afraid it wasn't carriage returns, see my reponse to Nutsch below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure If I am supposed to any answer my own question like this but I messed around with the bits of code I had above and mixed it with a mcaro I found and came up with the following code that is quite slow but it seems to do the trick for me. Thanks for all the input though!!

```
 Set rangetext = Cells.SpecialCells( _
 xlCellTypeConstants, _
 xlTextValues)
 For Each rangesheet In rangetext
 If Trim(rangesheet.Value) = "" Then
 rangesheet.ClearContents
 End If
 Next
Set rangetext = Nothing
Set rangesheet = Nothing




 Range("b1:AZ60").Select
 Set rng = Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange)
 For Each C In rng
   If IsEmpty(C) Then
   C.FormulaR1C1 = "=0"
   If C.Value = 0 Then
   C.ClearContents
   C.Select
   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
   Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
  End If

  End If
 Next C
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out which characters you have in these "blank" cells.

Select a cell and run the GetSelectionContents macro below:

```
Sub GetSelectionContents()
MsgBox sAnalyseString(selection)
End Sub

Function sAnalyseString(sSTR As String) As String
Dim lLoop As Long, sTemp As String

For lLoop = 1 To Len(sSTR)
    sTemp = sTemp & ", " & Asc(Mid(sSTR, lLoop, 1))
Next

sAnalyseString = Mid(sTemp, 2)

End Function
```

Then, once you have your mystery character, replace it before running your delete macro.

`Activesheet.usedrange.Replace What:=chr(32), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False`

Comment: Chip Pearson has a useful addin at his site called [CellView](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cellview.aspx) that will flag the characters

Comment: Hi @nutsch. I tried out your code. The Msgbox reported nothing for some cells and a series of 32s for others. 32 I've discovered is the ASCII symbol for a space. I thought the trim function can deal with spaces?